# Htaccess simple extension redirect

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have tried searching alot for a solution for this, but I simply can't find it.

I have an websever running Apache w/PHP (mod_rewrite enabled), and I want to simply do the following:

**Request from**

```
downloadedReports/testreport.pdf
```

**Request to**

```
downloadedReports/testreport.php
```

I currently have tried the following rewritecode:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   Options +FollowSymLinks
   Options +Indexes
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteRule .pdf $1.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

But it does not work at all.

*Notice:* I do not want to redirect the url/send the target to a different page. I just want to rewrite the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more googling and trying/failing I found a solution to the problem. Works as intended now!

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^.]+).pdf$ $1.php [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this article, it explains how to remove them:

http://alexcican.com/post/how-to-remove-php-html-htm-extensions-with-htaccess/

Removing Extensions
To remove the .php extension from a PHP file for example yoursite.com/wallpaper.php to yoursite.com/wallpaper you have to add the 
following code inside the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Or our purposes you change it to:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options +Indexes
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    ## Block acess to dirs
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    ## Block acess to files
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    ## Block acess for links
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    ## don't do anything
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]

    RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)\.(pdf)$ $1.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```